# Abrir programa compilado en terminal

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

Hola tengo un programa de consola en C, compila bien en Ubuntu pero al abrirlo no me genera la ventana de la consola, tengo que abrirlo desde la consola para poder conseguir esto

¿Que debo hacer para que el programa se abra automáticamente desde la consola?

[EDITADO] Información mas detallada:

ejemplo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("Hola Mundo");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

> gcc -o ejemplo ejemplo.c

se me genera un archivo que al hacerle doble click no se abre la terminal para mostrarme el mensaje, ahora si abro yo manualmente la terminal y me dirijo al directorio del programa y lo ejecuto:

> ./ejemplo

Este se ejecutando correctamente mostrándome toda la información y respetando el getchar();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usted tiene que hacer uso de [`system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) hasta donde yo se.

Por ejemplo si su SO tiene LXTerminal podría usar algo así:

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char cmd[50];

    strcpy(cmd,"lxterminal");
    system(cmd);

  return 0;
}
```

o bien `gnome-terminal` básicamente fíjese que se le pasa a `cmd` el comando fijado para abrir la consola a través de [`system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system), en este caso `gnome-terminal`.

```
 #include <string.h>

 int main()
 {
    char cmd[50];

    strcpy(cmd,"gnome-terminal");
    system(cmd);

  return 0;
 }
```

Ahora tendría que saber que consola usa su SO y cual es su comando para abrilo, después adaptar el código a su programa.

---

Quizás con el ejemplo anterior no le quedo muy claro le dejare una idea, pero tómesela como **pseudocode**. Es solo para ilustrar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("lock.dat", "rb+");  //simulamos un filelock

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        fptr = fopen("lock.dat", "wb"); //simulamos un filelock
        char cmd[50];

        //supongamos que su programa compilado se llama a.out, y se lo pasamos.    
        strcpy(cmd,"lxterminal -e \"./a.out\""); 
        system(cmd);


    }else{

        sleep(5);
        int a = 0;

        //test para que vea algo en la pantalla y no se cierre ect
        for (a = 0; a < 10000; a++){ 
            printf("Hola Mundo");
        }
        sleep(5);

        fclose(fptr);

        remove("lock.dat");
  }
  // Antes de terminar su programa tendría que desbloquear el filelock, si usa 
  // un fichero tiene que borrar este, para poder volver a lanzar su programa 
  // mas abajo dejo un link sobre filelock o tambien puede usar google
  return 0;
}
```

info : puede mirar para crear un filelock mas decente [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468238/file-locking-in-linux-using-c-programme)

Comment: Muchas gracias al final lo solucione creando 2 ejecutables, mi programa tal cual y otro que se encarga de abrir mi programa, este ultimo hace uso de system y de gnome-terminal -x para ejecutar mi programa, eso si para que funcione es necesario modificar los permisos de ejecución del programa que sera abierto si no recibiremos un aviso de permiso denegado.

Answer (score 8):

Resumiendo: **no puedes**.

En Windows, al compilar el programa, indicas si es en modo gráfico o en modo consola (si no lo haces tú, el compilador lo hace implicitamente). Si es un programa para consola, el sistema crea una *consola virtual*, que es la ventana que ves, para que tu programa interactue con ella.

En entornos no-Windows, tales como *nix, las cosas no funcionan así. **No** hay distinción; todo son programas, que interactuan con la entrada y salida estándar. Dichos mecanimos de entrada/salida **no siempre son físicos**; un programa puede crear una consola virtual, y pasarla como `STDIN` o `STDOUT` a otros programas *hijos*.

Ese es el mecanismo usado por los emuladores de terminal. Crean un proceso *hijo*, llamando al interprete de comandos. Cuando ejecutas un programa bajo ese interprete, este otro programa hereda `STDIN` y `STDOUT` del interprete que lo lanzó, que a su vez lo hereda del programa que lo creo, que, como dije, es la aplicación de terminal.

Ese mecanismo hace *distinto* el *auto-crear* una ventana de terminal para mostrar en ella tus resultados. Puedes invocar al emulador, pasandole un argumento, que sería tu propio programa a ejecutar; desde tu propio programa, has de diferenciar si te has *auto-invocado*, o has sido llamado de forma directa. Podrías usar el directorio `/proc`, o crear algún tipo de archivo *cerrojo*, o un *socket* de red, o usar *DBUS*, ...

Consejo final: salvo que *necesites* crear tu propio terminal por algo, es mucho mas sencillo lanzar los programas desde el emulador de terminal proporcionado por el sistema.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta y debería ser aceptada.

Comment: lo siento @toledano pero el "no se puede" no esta en mi diccionario

Gracias por tu información Dolmenes creo que es importante todo aquello que mencionaste

Answer (score 1):

vamos que los programas no se abren con doble clic y tendrás la orden de terminal XD

Mejor pon: `nano mi_programita.desktop`

Y metes algo como:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.1
Name=Mi Programa
Comment=Mi programa
Exec=/ruta/de/tu/programa
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

Y ya nomás le das permisos de ejecutable:

> chmod +x mi_programita.desktop

Igual puedes meterlo en `/usr/share/applications` para que salga en el menú y poner el argumento `Icon=/ruta/del/icono.extension` para ponerle un icono, es lo mejor que puedes hacer, debes pausar el programa al final si no: no podrás ver la aplicación.

NOTA: si no usas argumentos es mejor no usar `int argc, char const *argv[]` en `int main(...)` y dejarlo como `int main() {`

Comment: Jajaja Windows y macOS me tienen acostumbrado xd

Comment: jaja de todas maneras es recomendable mejor que no edites tanto el código y no pongas cosas no necesarias y mejor hagas el desktop, te manda la orden que se abra con terminal, o etc