# ¿Cómo cambiar el fondo de la terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, gnu

Tengo un proyecto en el cual debo cambiar el fondo de la terminal

Vi muchos ejemplos pero para windows y casi no veo en GNU/linux es en el sistema que me encuentro en este momento.

**Nota:** siempre me mencionan a la funcion `system()`; pero según yo esa solo sirve para windows y su terminal.

Comment: le deje unos ejemplos al final, puede probarlos y si es lo que busca, quizas se ahorre leer toda la respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bien su pregunta puede contar con muchas formas de hacerlo, le expongo algunas (ideas/enfoques):

## **1**

basada en lo que usted comenta de [`system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Tendria que saber que terminal tiene su OS por ejemplo si tiene LXTerminal, este permite que se cambien hasta donde yo se desde la ventana de la misma:

```
Edit > Preferences > Style > color
```

Ahora bien esto es solo supociciones pues en principio me parece algo engorroso siempre contando de la terminal/OS este diseñada para hacer algo similar (tengo grandes dudas de si se penso para hacer algo similar).

podria usar algo asi:

fijese que se le pasa a `cmd` el comando "fiticio"

```
 #include <string.h>

 int main()
 {
    char cmd[50];

    strcpy(cmd,"lxterminal -e \" parametros para cambiar el color \""); //supongamos que su programa compilado se llama a.out, y se lo pasamos.
        
    system(cmd);

//..
```

pero de existir un comando para esto, lo anterior lo que haria seria abrir una nueva consola ect. se tendria que investigar si se le podria pasar el parametro a la terminal activa mediante system() de manera similar a la mencionada.

Mi conlusion sobre este enfoque a simple vista me parece que existen muchas variables para que no funcione.

*en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52216/abrir-programa-compilado-en-terminal/52240#52240) se trata un tema que quizas lo ayude.*

---

## **2**

Otro enfoque podria ser, el de que mediante su programa, este modifique los fiheros de configuracion o remplaze los que usa la terminal para el uso scheme ect.

.Xdefaults

```
! Xft settings ---------------------------------------------------------------

Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight

!! simple_rainbow
*background:  #575757
*foreground:  #dcdccc

!black
*color0:      #666666
*color8:      #888888
!red
*color1:      #ff8278
*color9:      #ff8278
!green
*color2:      #bde077
*color10:     #bde077
!yellow
*color3:      #eadc84
*color11:     #eadc84
!blue
*color4:      #77bee0
*color12:     #77bee0
!magenta
*color5:      #dd91f3
*color13:     #dd91f3
!cyan
*color6:      #ffc178
*color14:     #ffc178
!white
*color7:      #dddddd
*color15:     #cccccc
```

.bashrc

```
# Add nano as default editor
export EDITOR=nano

alias lss='ls -Fa --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
[ ! "$UID" = "0" ] && archbey2

PS1="\[\033[1;34m\][\$(date +%H%M)][\u@\h:\w]$\[\033[0m\] "
#Tried the above command to test
```

dependera del terminal, me parece mas sencillo este enfoque, y mas si sabe que colores quiere, "solo habria" que modifiarlos y cargarlos, no creo que con el uso de system() sea muy complicado, aun asi habria que investigar, porque quizas existe una forma mucho mas facil.

info: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=51818&p=9

---

## **3**

Esta se la dejo para el final, porque no se si en base a su pregunta este enfoque se podria usar, (aunque yo creo que este es el que usaria si quisiera que un cli tuviera un color personalizado ect.).

No se si conoces [Ncurses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), con esta libreria puedes cambiar el aspecto en el que se muestra su programa, quizas es lo que busca.

Aunque Ncurses va mucho mas alla de cambiar los colores, si lo que quiero es personalizar el programa usaria esta libreria.

info: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/color.html

---

P.D:

system() funciona para GNU/Linux pero es muy probable que los comandos no se le pasan no sean los mismo que usted vio para windows, ademas de tener en cuenta que es uno OS diferente, tambien tener en cuenta que terminales en GNU/Linux existen muchas con lo que posiblemente los comandos sean tambien diferentes "en el caso de poderse hacer como usted lo vio en windows".

> ## **UPDATE**

Probando por curiosidad quizas esta sea la forma mas simple para lo que busca:

```
//..
char cmd[50];
strcpy(cmd,"echo -test \"\e[97m\e[41m\"");
system(cmd);

sleep(5);

int a = 0;
for (a = 0; a < 10000; a++){
printf("Hola Mundo");

sleep(5);
..//
```

Usando el enfoque ANSI:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI

---

Quizas esto no lo nesecita pero se lo dejo, es para cambiar en color de las letras textos, funciona en entornos tipo UNIX:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RED   "\x1B[31m"
#define GRN   "\x1B[32m"
#define YEL   "\x1B[33m"
#define BLU   "\x1B[34m"
#define MAG   "\x1B[35m"
#define CYN   "\x1B[36m"
#define WHT   "\x1B[37m"
#define RESET "\x1B[0m"

int main()
{
  printf(RED "red\n" RESET);
  printf(GRN "green\n" RESET);
  printf(YEL "yellow\n" RESET);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excelente información me ayudó gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando **setterm** puedes cambiar el color de fondo de la terminal

este escript  funciona desde una virtual terminal , para ver su funcionamiento accede : ctrl + alt + f1 *(por ejemplo)*, haces login  y ejecutas el siguiente script  de ejemplo.

```
#!/bin/bash

setterm -background blue

setterm -foreground white


printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "Esta Terminal contiene:" "-Fondo Azul" "-Fuente Blanca";

sleep 8;
tput reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Es mas sencillo, si usas la secuencia de escape \033 en cualquier printf o en cualquier cout, por ejemplo:

en C:

```
printf("\033[1;44mHola mundo!\033[0m");
```

en C++:

```
cout << "\033[1;44mHola mundo!\033[0m" << endl;
```

en esta pagina hay mas informacion sobre la lista de colores de letra, fondo, aplicar negrita, etc., al terminal de linux en tiempo de ejecucion, similar al system(color ) del lenguaje C/C++ en Windows:

https://robologs.net/2016/03/31/como-colorear-el-output-de-la-terminal-en-linux/

Yo lo probe usando codeblocks en ubuntu 14.04 y funciona usando el codeblocks.

Aqui un ejemplo bonito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("\033[1;41m ________________                              \n");
  printf("|           |    |                                \n");
  printf("|           |____|________                        \n");
  printf("|                         |                       \n");
  printf("|_________________________|                       \n");
  printf(" /  \\             /  \\                            \n");
  printf("|    |           |    |                           \n");
  printf("_\\__/_____________\\__/__________________________  \n");
  printf("________________________________________________  \033[0m\n ");
  getchar();

  system("clear");


  printf("\033[1;44m          _________________               \n");
  printf("        |    |            |               \n");
  printf(" _______|____|            |               \n");
  printf("|                         |               \n");
  printf("|_________________________|               \n");
  printf("    /  \\             /  \\                 \n");
  printf("   |    |           |    |                \n");
  printf("____\\__/_____________\\__/_________________\n");
  printf("__________________________________________\033[0m\n ");
getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Aunque el cambio sea por lineas o renglones, se puede usar la creatividad para que abarque todo el terminal ;) .

Espero que halla servido de ayuda.

Saludos a todos.